# Arrays getting elements

Tags: java, arrays

i have an answers array with ten elements. how could i check to see if the element at index 3 is b for example.

```
ArrayList<String>answers = new ArrayList<String>();

answers.add("c");
answers.add("a");
answers.add("b");
answers.add("c");
answers.add("a");
answers.add("d");
answers.add("a");
answers.add("c");
answers.add("b");
answers.add("d");

//im trying to put it in here with the if else loop
if() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( b1, "Correct!");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b1, "Incorrect!");
}
```

Comment: `answers.get(3).equals("b")`?...

Comment: Also, `if` and `else` aren't part of a loop construct. They're *flow control*, but don't fall under the loop category of control.

Comment: @Jashaszun You are right but `"b".equals(answers.get(3))` is safer.

Comment: @Xebax why is this safer?

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz Because `"b"` is not `null`, so it will never throw a `NullPointerException`, whereas `answers.get(3)` could be `null`.

Comment: but if `answes.get(3)` is null, irremediably will throw NPE independently of the order... so, knowing that will be a NPE, whats the difference between throwing an exception in `"b".equals(answers.get(3)` and `answers.get(3).equals("b")`?

Comment: sorry, I have read, and the first one will not throw a NPE exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answers.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("b") //returns true or false.
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the element at index i, use

```
yourArray.get(i)
```

To compare Strings in java, use

```
myString.equals(yourString)
```

So the answer you are looking for is

```
answers.get(3).equals("b")
```